# Displaying first row data in Report Header

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that accepts EmpID as parameter and list all departments of the employee.  The report is run for one  employee at a time. However it will list the EmpID and EmpName in the report result.

Now, I need to display the emp name in the `report header`. I understand I can use a second query to fetch the emp name. However, I am looking for any alternative approach that we can use to list the emp name without running a different query (since we already have the data in the query result).

Is there a way to do that in `SSRS 2005`?

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: With the following approach, it didn't work when exported to excel. The EmpName didn't come on the header

Follow the steps below

1. Put a textbox (with ID txtPlantName) in the **report body**  (**above** table for the report)

   > = "Employee " & First(Fields!EmpName.Value, "dsInboundContainer")
2. Refer [How to display dataset Field value in Page Header of SSRS report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e2bce70-43f5-4e36-9432-12fb762ccffe/how-to-display-dataset-field-value-in-page-header-of-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices)
3. Use another textbox in the **header** with following expression.

   > =ReportItems!txtPlantName.Value

Also refer [Fields in Page Header - SSRS 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/26/fields-in-page-header.aspx)

> One of the small new features in Reporting Services 2008 that has not been widely publicized, is the ability to directly reference dataset fields and dataset aggregations from expressions in the page header and page footer.  You can accomplish this by simply dragging a dataset field directly into the page header/footer area of the report, or by manually writing expressions.

Note: When we use Edit Expressions, it has a `DataSet` which has `First` already present.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the FIRST() function in an Expression to snag only the first row of data from a dataset.  Sometimes you may need to order the data, to make sure you're getting the right row, but in your situation that may not be necessary.

Note that FIRST() is scoped to your grouping level.